# Parse everything behind FQDN as a variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do a redirect with htaccess but somehow this does not seem to work.

I would like to pick up everything behind the full qualified domainname and parse it as an variable to php so that my URL's look like:

```
https://example.com/?abc.com
```

In the background it should do:

```
https://example.com/index.php?url=abc.com
```

Something similar i'm already doing with another link but somehow this does not seem to work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong here and i'm starting to doubt this isnt possible

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> QSA|qsappend When the replacement URI contains a query string, the
>   default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

You also can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/index.php?url=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

because without variable name it's not easy to use

Comment: Sadly that does not work. It will put a large number of index.php?url= behind fqdn

`https://example.com/index.php?url=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.phpurl=index.htmlabc.com`